# Custom classes for attachments

Tags: custom-field, attachment-fields-to-edit

I'm trying to create a custom field in ATTACHMENT DETAILS section. I want to add in this field multiply words separated by space which will be than added as a classes to particular images.

This is the solution I've found so far. It adds custom field but it doesn't add a class to images. What is wrong here?

```
function add_attachment_classes_field( $form_fields, $post ) {
$field_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'classes', true );
  $form_fields['classes'] = array(
    'value' => $field_value ? $field_value : '',
    'label' => __( 'Classes' ),
    'helps' => __( 'Add class seperated by space' )
  );
 return $form_fields;
}
add_filter( 'attachment_fields_to_edit', 'add_attachment_classes_field', 10, 2 );

function save_attachment_classes( $attachment_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['classes'] ) ) {
   $classes = $_REQUEST['attachments'][$attachment_id]['classes'];
   update_post_meta( $attachment_id, 'classes', $classes );
  }
}
add_action( 'edit_attachment', 'save_attachment_classes' );
```

Comment: There is already builtin CSS Class field in WordPress. Why are you adding new one?

Comment: @VinodDalvi I want to set different classes for images for portfolio sorting purposes.

Comment: Ok. I have added answer for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the following code in functions.php file of your theme which will add your custom added classes to images when you will insert it into post editor.

```
function add_image_class($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){
$classes = get_post_meta( $id, 'classes', true );
if ( preg_match('/<img.*? class=".*?">/', $html) ) {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*? class=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . $classes . '$2', $html);
} else {
    $html = preg_replace('/(<img.*?)>/', '$1 class="' . $classes . '" >', $html);
}
return $html;
}
add_filter('image_send_to_editor','add_image_class',10,8);
```

Comment: I'm getting this output: <p><a href="http://localhost/..." rel="attachment wp-att-821"><img src="http://localhost/....jpg" alt="alt" width="1170" height="780" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-821" / class="classone" ></a></p>

Comment: And how can i make it work on gallery thumbnail? That's what i needed in the first place actually.

Comment: That's why i was telling you there is already builtin CSS Class field in WordPress where you can add your custom classes for images of portfolio. You can access it from advanced settings of image.

Comment: I'm using WP 3.6 and can only see Caption, Alternative Text and Description fields.

Comment: You can access it using following steps.
Insert image in post editor.
Click on image.
Click on edit image button.
In opened dialog box, click on advanced settings.